# Webpack, multiple entry points Sass and JS

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack, entry-point

Below is my webpack config. At the moment the file loads this main.js entry point

```
import './resources/assets/js/app.js';
import './resources/assets/sass/main.scss';
```

I can get both files in the public/js files but I would like to get the css and js in their own folder. Is this possible?

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
let ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');

module.exports = {

    resolve: {
    alias: {
      'masonry': 'masonry-layout',
      'isotope': 'isotope-layout'
    }
  },

    entry: './main.js',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [

         {  test: /\.js$/, 
                exclude: /node_modules/, 
                loader: "babel-loader?presets[]=es2015",

             },

            {
                test:/\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: [{loader:'css-loader?sourceMap'}, {loader:'sass-loader', options: {
                    sourceMap: true
                }}],

                })
            },

            /*{
        test    : /\.(png|jpg|svg)$/,
        include : path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
        loader  : 'url-loader?limit=30000&name=images/[name].[ext]'
    }, */

            {
                 test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },



        ]
    },

    plugins: [

        //new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('app.css'),
        new WebpackNotifierPlugin(),

    ]

};
```

Answer (score 28):

Yes you can do this, here's an example that does not require you to import sass files in your js files:

```
const config = {
    entry: {
        main: ['./assets/js/main.js', './assets/css/main.scss'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {test: /\.(css|scss)/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader'])}
            // ...  
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path: './assets/bundles/',
        filename: "[name].min.js",
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: '[name].min.css',
        }),
        // ...
    ]
    // ...
}
```

You should end up with `./assets/bundles/main.min.js` and `./assets/bundles/main.min.css`. You will have to add js rules obviously.

Answer (score 24):

We have multiple entry points and outputs and define them like this:

```
entry: {
    'js/main.min.js': './resources/assets/js/app.js', 
    'css/main.min.scss': './resources/assets/sass/main.scss'
},
output: {  
    filename: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/assets/[name]')
},
```

webpack reads the keys of the entry and replaces them into the `[name]` tag in the output filename. [See documentation for "output filename"](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-filename)

Comment: It works, but the it's just a hack to generate a `scss` file extension. The content of `main.min.scss` will **still** be Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

`ExtractTextPlugin` has been deprecated for CSS and the recommended approach is using `MiniCssExtractPlugin`.

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['index.js', 'index.css'],
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
      use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name]-[hash].css'
    })
  ]
};
```

You will also need to install `npm i node-sass` separately.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar need, not sure if this is the correct way of doing it but it works for me.

```
output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './public/js'),
        filename:'bundle.js'
    },
```

Then for the css:

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("../css/[name].css")
],
```

Comment: yes I thought about that, seems a bit wrong, having to negotiate your way back up the tree to then write the file. Thanks for the reply I will keep the question open and post if I find anything else.

Comment: Yeah I know it's kind of a hack but I really couldn't find a cleaner/correct way of doing it hah. I'll be interested to see what other solutions turn up because this is something I've been wanting to revamp in my webpack projects hah.

Answer (score 2):

I have an admin panel(panel.js and panel.scss) and non-admin content pages(index.js and main.scss), I want to compile to 2 css files and 2 js files
This is what I did:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'pages': ['./src/js/index.js', './src/css/main.scss'],
        'admin': ['./src/js/admin-index.js', './src/css/admin.scss']
    },

 output: {
            filename: "./js/[name]-bundle.js",
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"), 
        },

plugins: [
 new MiniCssExtractPlugin(
            {
                filename: "./css/[name].css"
            }
        ),
   ]

}
```

The result came as:

```
dist
    css
        admin.css
        pages.css
    js
        admin-bundle.js
        pages-bundle.js
```

Worked pretty well, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The `mini-css-extract-plugin` can fix it with webpack 5

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/js/index.js', './src/scss/index.scss'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }, {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name]-[hash].css'
    }),
  ]
};
```