# Extracting sass as css using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

First. I know questions like this were asked, but I am missing something to understand them. I am trying to compile scss to css. And I would like webpack to basically do the same as `sass app.scss : app.css`. I tried to configure it using `extract-text-webpack-plugin`, but I am doing something wrong or missing smth.

It worked if I `include(app.scss)` in `app.js` but this makes no sense because if anyone has disabled JavaScript the styles won't work.

This is my `webpack.config.js` file. I have no idea how to do it.

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var jsConfig = {
  entry: "./_dev/scripts/app.js",
  output: { filename: "./scripts/bundle.js" },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
};

var scssConfig = {
  entry: "./_dev/scss/app.scss",
  output: { filename: "./content/app.css" },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({filename:"./_dev/scss/app.scss"}),
  ]
};

var config = [scssConfig, jsConfig];

module.exports = config;
```

Edit: I also found this. This series would have helped with all my questions so if you have similar questions make sure to read it before asking!

https://codeburst.io/simple-beginner-guide-for-webpack-2-0-from-scratch-part-v-495dba627718

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include your `app.scss` for `webpack` to be able to find your `scss` references because `webpack` will traverse your project and apply loaders to all files it can find through references starting from `app.js` recursively down. If you don't have references to `app.scss` somewhere in the project `webpack` can't find it and it won't build it. So in the entry of you project (assume it is `app.js`) you need to do this:

```
import 'relative/path/to/styles/app.scss';
```

But it doesn't mean that those who don't have `js` enabled won't receive your styles. You need to include `app.scss` only for the `build` phase of your project, after that your styles will be included in `html` and will be loaded even for those without `js` enabled.

[webpack concepts](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/#entry) section explains how `webpack` finds dependencies based on your `entry` point building its internal graph of dependencies.

---

Update:

There is a way that allows you to not add your `app.scss` in your `js`. You can include multiple files in your entry object in your `webpack` config. Here is an example of how configuration might look in your case:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var config = {
  entry: {
     main: [
        "./_dev/scripts/app.js", 
        "./_dev/scss/app.scss"
     ],
  },
  output: { 
    path: './scripts',
    filename:  "bundle.js" 
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("./_dev/scss/app.scss"),
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

More information available on SO question [webpack-multiple-entry-points-sass-and-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813050/webpack-multiple-entry-points-sass-and-js).

You also have incorrect configuration of `ExtractTextPlugin` in `webpack`. You are placing the whole path in the option for `filename`, which is not correct. In your case it should look like this:

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("./_dev/scss/app.css"),
  ]
```

Comment: I thought I was doing it. Could please you give me a code example?

Comment: So in my app.js I put `require('./path.to/app.scss'`? And where does the `.css` file go?

Comment: yes, `require` if you don't use `imports`. Updated with more config for `ExtractTextPlugin`.

Comment: sorry, answered a bit too fast. I see you wanted to separate `js` and `scss` entries in you `webpack` config, there is a way to do this and then you don't need to include `scss` files in your `js`. See the update with corrected configuration.

Comment: I actually neded to do this: `plugins: [new ExtractTextPlugin("./content/app.css")]` but other than that it works perfectly, Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help :) I didn't know that you can have `webpack` config with separate objects for `js` and `css`, so I learnt something new from the question and our discussion :)