# VUE CLI / WEBPACK - Generate /public .css files from scss

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

What should I do to have a .scss file at my /src/assets compiled to /public folder?

I started a project using VUE CLI.

Answer (score 0):

in your `main.ts`

```
import '@/assets/main.scss';
```

Comment: Thanks, but doing that the file will be inserted at the bundle. I don't want this. I want to have my .scss file compiled to .css and pushed at the /public so I can have access it from a unique url like  myapp.com/my-file.css

Comment: oh ok sorry I misunderstood the question.
check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61897037/2246035